# Rewrite rules from Apache .htaccess to lighttpd standard

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I'm new to **lighttpd** and I'm having problems with the **.htaccess**, I know that it's not the same as Apache and you have to do the changes in **lighttpd.conf** so I'm trying to do my rewrite rules, but they are not working for some reason...

This is my **.htaccess** file in Apache and I would like if you can convert it for lighttpd so it works on my server, for **index.php** to open as `/index` I tried `url.rewrite-once = ( "^index$" => "/index.php" )`, but it wasn't working so please if you can convert at least the following and if you have time for the other ones convert them as well. By the way, just to let you know, I enabled `mod_rewrite` from **modules.conf** so it's possible to use rewrite rules, but as I said I can't convert them right or I don't know what I'm doing wrong ...

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^view_news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?id=$1 [L]



ErrorDocument 404 /error.php - NOT SOLVED

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^your-site\.com$ NOT SOLVED
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.your-site.com/$1 [R=301,L] - NOT SOLVED

RewriteRule ^index$ /index.php [L] - SOLVED
RewriteRule ^view_news/([^/]*)$ /news.php?id=$1 [L] - SOLVED
```

Comment: Looks to me that at in the example you provided you should have `url.rewrite-once = ( "^/index$" => "/index.php" )` (addition of a leading `/`). The same will apply to `view_news`, the match should include the leading slash.

Comment: Macattack - thank's allot man, could you please help me with the other ones if you have some time and I see you have good knowledge in lighttpd so can you leave some contact so I can contact you, email would be great ... :)

Comment: If you post what you've done for each, what you expect them to do, and what they appears to be doing, I can point out any errors you have that I see. I won't just convert them because SO isn't a site to post "do this for me" requests. Also, I don't know Apache rewrite syntax, so I don't even know what the above rules mean.

Comment: I got the most right but i'm having a problem with the 404 error page, in Apache is this ErrorDocument 404 /error.php, but don't know about lighttpd so as forbidden, I wan't to find out how I can forbidden surten folder ...

Comment: server.error-handler-404 = "/error-404.php" - any ideas why this is no working?

Comment: To your first question [mod_access](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/Docs_ModAccess) describes how to disallow access to directories, be aware that it is lighttpd version specific. As far as the 404 handler, I'd guess that maybe lighttpd isn't allowed to run php files from the root directory, or otherwise doesn't have permission to serve it. Try putting a straight html file in, or navigating directly to it to see if it'll open then.

Comment: well the 404 handler is not in root directory, i'm trying to put it in my site where I made the virtual host and it's in /home/user/public_html and I insert in /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf the 404 handler, but no efect, how can I check my lighttpd version too?

Comment: You can do `lighttpd --version` on the command line or look at the headers returned, such as in chrome developer tools. Mine is `lighttpd 1.4.28`. Make sure you can access the file by putting in your browser `http://yourdomain/error-404.php` first. Then worry about the `server.error-handler-404 = ...`.

Comment: yes I can access the files error-404.php in my browser but does not work with the error handler ...